# Why does my Java JUnit 5 Timeout Test PASS when the execution in milliseconds exceeds what was specified?

Tags: java, junit, annotations, timeout, junit5

### What i'm trying to do:

*Fail the test after 2 milliseconds*

Here's an example of my code.
It varies between 12-22 ms.
I've discovered that if i change the value to '1' it will sometimes even fail at seemingly random times..

```
@Test
@Timeout(unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, value = 2)

public void hundredCities() {

    assertEquals(740,
            stringAlgorithm.findTotalLengthOfStringArray(
                    new String[] {
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam" })
    );

}
```

However...

[Test passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTZof.png)

What am i doing wrong here?

String algorithm code:

public class StringAlgorithm {

```
public int findTotalLengthOfStringArray(String[] test) {
    // String[] test = {"Bananas", "Apples"};
    String s = "";

    for (String i : test) {
        s += i;
    }

    char [] c = s.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(c.length);

    return c.length;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time reported by IntelliJ IDEA may not accurately reflect the execution time of the test method. In particular, the time reported for the first test executed includes time spent setting up the test suite. You can see by adding another test method earlier in the test class that the time "moves" to that test, and `hundredCities` itself may very well execute within the 2ms timeout duration.

You can verify this by logging and asserting the time taken explicitly:

```
@Test
public void hundredCities() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    assertEquals(740,
            stringAlgorithm.findTotalLengthOfStringArray(
                    new String[] {
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam",
                            "Stockholm", "Paris", "London", "New York", "Amsterdam" })
    );
    long executionTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(Duration.ofNanos(executionTime).toMillis());
    assertTrue(executionTime < 2_000_000);
}
```

On my machine, I had to add around a thousand cities before it consistently took greater than 2ms. Of course, that threshold will vary on different hardware, operating systems, Java versions, etc.

Comment: This makes more sense..are there any best practices so that I can accurately work with timeout tests? Also thank you for the answer!

Comment: Sure thing, @AnotherApple! To be honest, I've never used this `@Timeout` annotation before, although I have sometimes done explicit time assertions like in my answer. I would say it's probably not intended for very short (<10ms) timeouts, and I would probably only use it for timeouts measured in seconds (the default time unit). Timing on the JVM is not generally precise enough to measure things in single-digit milliseconds. One poorly-timed garbage collection could cause your test to fail even if there's nothing wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: It's probably more suitable for testing network timeouts, algorithms that involve variable sleep times or complex lock acquisition, just to ensure that a bug can't cause the entire test suite to hang indefinitely.

Comment: If you're looking to benchmark an algorithm, [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) is a more accurate way to do it.